# Style a submit input to look like a span with bootstrap glyphicon styling using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, form-submit

I have an link with a span which uses bootstrap classes to display a trash icon. All this is in MVC

so:

```
<a href=@Url.Action("Delete", "Site", new { siteID = Model.SiteId, clientID = Model.ClientID }) >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" />
</a>
```

I now have an input which I want to style in the same way but with a print icon. The input is a submit input and I want the form to post back with a file with is selected in another input. All wrapped in a form.

Here is my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Print", "Site", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input name="file" type="file">

    <input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="javascript: form.action='@Url.Action("Print", new { clientID = Model.ClientID, siteID = Model.SiteID })' " />
}
```

I would like to like the input to look as if it was a span with bootstrap styling so I want it to look like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" />
```

Can anyone help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change input type to button

```
<button type="submit" onclick="some action"><span class="fa fa-area-chart"></span></button>
```

this was you can add span in between button

Comment: Nearly, don't want the button 'style' I just want the print icon to appear.

Comment: Sorted. I've added a bit of styling and it look fine now. Thanks